# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException iam getting this error on google play crash reports

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException**

**com.xxxxx.xxxx.deeplink$xWebViewClient.onReceivedError**

i have a webviwe with onReceivedError function as i will explain it in my code below
and iam getting the above errors how can i slove it ?

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(facebook.this).inflate(R.layout.errror_dialog, viewGroup, false);
        Button tryagain = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tryagain);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(facebook.this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        webview.setVisibility((View.INVISIBLE));
        tryagain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                webview.reload();
                webview.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
                alertDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a race condition, caused by trying to update views in your dialog when its already off screen.  If possible, fix the race condition.  But in general you can just catch and ignore this exception.

If you're getting this when showing the dialog, that means you no longer have permission to draw to the screen with that Context, and you need to use the proper one.

Comment: then this exception is not causing the app to crash ?

Comment: i have tried it on my phone and iam not getting crash

Comment: Any exception that's uncaught will cause a crash.  But if an exception is one you can recover from, you can catch it and ignore the exception.  This is one that can frequently be recovered from.